# pagination buttons limits in yii2

Tags: php, button, pagination, yii2, limit

I need in my gridview pagination there show only 3 elements and then in the button pagination show 3 buttons but the button change dynamically.

example buttons pagination:

```
[1]-2-3...
```

click in second element

```
[2]-3-4...
```

my code:

```php
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Area::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 3,
        ],
    ]);
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in gridview with the `pager` attribute

```
     <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summaryOptions' => ['class' =>'dfenx_pagination_summary',],
    'pager' => ['options' => ['class' => 'pagination pull-right']],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pager' => [
        'maxButtonCount'=>3,    // Set maximum number of page buttons that can be displayed
        ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      ..........
```

this are the option available for pager

```
    'pager' => [
        'options'=>['class'=>'pagination'],   // set clas name used in ui list of pagination
        'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',   // Set the label for the "previous" page button
        'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',   // Set the label for the "next" page button
        'firstPageLabel'=>'First',   // Set the label for the "first" page button
        'lastPageLabel'=>'Last',    // Set the label for the "last" page button
        'nextPageCssClass'=>'next',    // Set CSS class for the "next" page button
        'prevPageCssClass'=>'prev',    // Set CSS class for the "previous" page button
        'firstPageCssClass'=>'first',    // Set CSS class for the "first" page button
        'lastPageCssClass'=>'last',    // Set CSS class for the "last" page button
        'maxButtonCount'=>10,    // Set maximum number of page buttons that can be displayed
        ],
```